# Virtual scroll on primeng table: scroll height issue

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using primeng p-table (v9.0.0) with virtual scrolling (both horizontal and vertical scrollbars) and lazy loading. I've managed to make it work with automatic row height and row expansion (have two variables: with shown and loaded data, have table value connected to shown data only, lazy load method adds portion of loaded data to shown data, and total rows, if size of loaded data is not equal to size of shown data, is shown data length + 1). All this works OK unless I have small enough loaded data set so it does not require scrolling. In this case, virtual scroll ignores defined scroll height, and "collapses" (shrinks vertically to assumed total height of rows) - but it does not account for own horizontal scroll bar, and, as the result, I'm getting vertical scroll on very small table. Furthermore, height is not adjusted when row expansion is shown.

Is there any way to prevent virtual scroll for p-table to always follow the scroll height set for it, and not to decrease it even if total row height is not enough? Or, maybe, there is another way to make it always work and look the way it currently works and looks with large set of data?

Apologies for absence of code, I can't provide current state due to employer policy.